# Working with Mercurial Tags

Tags: mercurial, tags

I need to make changes to the code in a Mecurial repo that has been tagged. I cloned the repo locally and then issued an hg checkout TAGNAME. - which updated my local repo with the changeset represented by the TAGNAME tag. I then proceeded to make my fixes. My question is : What happens when I commit my changes from the same local repo? Will these changes be commited to the changeset TAGNAME or will these changes move into the tip? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you commit, a new changeset would be created, which parent is TAGNAME changeset. in fact it is a branch

And if this is the newest change, your changeset would be "tip".